# Passing conditions to mixins in LESS

Tags: css, less, conditional-statements

First of all, I am using LESS 1.7 (and there is no way I can change it). I have the following if-mixin in my less file that is just supposed to set the property and its value if the condition is met:

```
.if(@condition, @property, @value) when (@condition){
   @{property}: @value !important;
}
```

It works fine if I pass the condition as true/false like this:

```
.column-header {
    font-family: 'Something';
    .if(true, color, green);
}
```

However, I am not able to pass the condition as an expression. If I want to pass a comparison such as `2 > 1`, I get a parsing error: `expected ')' got '>'`. Is this not supported (or was this not supported in 1.7)? Am I doing something wrong? Any workaround? Thanks!

Comment: Prior to v3.x statements like `2 > 1` treated as conditional expressions *only* in `when` guards. In v3.+ there're functions like [`boolean` and `if`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#logical-functions).

Comment: @seven-phases-max That's unlucky but thanks for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not shure it's possible to pass contions to mixin.

But you can just write code witout `.if` mixin:

```
.column-header {
    font-family: 'Something';

    & when (2 > 1) {
        color: green;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, as the comment mentions it is not possible to achieve it in 1.7 so I ended up using your approach. Thanks.